# sqlplus trigger compilation error

Tags: sql, triggers, sqlplus

Is it a syntax error, am i missing a space or a ':' in my code. Below is my code for create trigger

```
  SQL> Create or replace  trigger trig_addr_mulund
      2  After insert or update
      3  On users_table
      4  For each row
      5  begin
      6  If :new.address like 'Mulund' then
      7  Insert into D12B_A23.user_mulund@ralink values (:new.id,:new.role_id,:new.b
    ranch_id,:new.name,:new.email,:new.phone,:new.address,
      8  :new.email,:new.phone,:new.address);
      9  Else
     10  Insert into D12B_A14.user_not_mulund@rslink values (:new.id,:new.role_id,:n
    ew.branch_id,:new.name,:new.email,:new.phone,:new.address,
     11  :new.email,:new.phone,:new.address);
     12  End if
     13  End;
     14  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

Comment: Use `show errors` after seeing that warning, or query the `user_errors` view, to see the actual compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon in your line 12 near `END IF`

Since you are doing a direct comparison, use `=` instead of `LIKE`.
 Also, It's recommended to provide the column names explicitly in your SQL statements.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_addr_mulund AFTER
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE ON users_table FOR EACH row
BEGIN 
  IF :new.address = 'Mulund' THEN    -- changed "LIKE" to "="
  INSERT
  INTO D12B_A23.user_mulund@ralink VALUES
    (
      :new.id,
      :new.role_id,
      :new.branch_id,
      :new.name,
      :new.email,
      :new.phone,
      :new.address,
      :new.email,
      :new.phone,
      :new.address
    );
ELSE
  INSERT
  INTO D12B_A14.user_not_mulund@rslink VALUES
    (
      :new.id,
      :new.role_id,
      :new.branch_id,
      :new.name,
      :new.email,
      :new.phone,
      :new.address,
      :new.email,
      :new.phone,
      :new.address
    );
END IF; -- added the missing semicolon
END;
/
```